# Is it forbidden to pray two rakat after Asr, or is it recommended?

Tags: prayer-timings

I recently came across these two hadiths:

Narrated ‘Aisha: Allah’s Messenger never missed two Rakat before the Fajr prayer and after the Asr
prayer openly and secretly.
Sahih Bukhari 1:10:566

Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah's Apostle forbade the offering of two prayers: 1. after the morning prayer till the sunrises. 2. after the 'Asr prayer till the sun sets.
Sahih Bukhari 1:10:562

Now I'm confused. Should I offer two rakat after Asr, or no?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it's forbidden to pray after Asr until sunset. By the way, some scholar allows pray have a reason, such as wudu's pray.

So why Rasulullah *peace be upon him* do it?

One time Rasulullah *peace be upon him* miss the Sunnah of Duhur pray, therefore, he prays the missed pray after Asr. Normally, Rasulullah *peace be upon him* when doing obedience he keeps it up.

To sum up, this worship related with Rasulullah *peace be upon him* and we are not allowed to follow.

*Source in Arabic https://islamqa.info/ar/217403

Comment: Why does the Hadith say he never missed two rakat after Asr then? Sorry, I'm not sure you answered my question! Or maybe I just don't understand it. :( And the only source is in Arabic, which I can't read...

Comment: No, we are not allowed to pray after Asr. Good to know not all Rasulullah worship is permitted to us.